# In my python script why is there a syntax error on the letter "r" in rho

Tags: python

I am trying to write a very simple script and I have little experience coding, I downloaded numpy and matplotlib and all that on my computer and am writing this script with some help and don't know why there are so many errors. I have already fixed some of the errors on there with questions from this website.

I have tried shortening it I dont know why it wont work. Its the first rho line keeps giving me syntax error

```
print("airplane");

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = 32.2  

rho = 0.00231  

S = 279  

W = 7000  

c0 = 928

c1 = 0.1

c2 = -0.002

d0 = 0.2

d1 = 0.0015

V0 = 0  

x0 = 0  

alpha0 = np.radians(-7)  

alpha_gr = np.radians(4)  

efficiency = 0.9  

lift_slope = np.radians(0.1167)  

max_lift_coef = 2.1  

dt = 0.05  


def thrust(V):

    return c0 + c1*V + c2*V**2



def drag_fuselage_tail(V):

    return d0*V + d1*V**2


def lift(V, alpha):

    return 0.5  rho  V**2  S  (lift_slope * alpha + max_lift_coef)


def drag(V, alpha):

    return 0.5  rho  V**2  S  (0.009 + (lift_coef(V, alpha)**2) / (np.pi  efficiency  S))


def acceleration(V, alpha):

    return (thrust(V) - drag(V, alpha) - drag_fuselage_tail(V)) / W - g * np.sin(alpha)


def rk4_step(V, x, alpha):

    k1v = dt * acceleration(V, alpha)

    k1x = dt * V

    k2v = dt  acceleration(V + (0.5)*k1v, alpha)

    k2x = dt  (V + (0.5)*k1v)

    k3v = dt  acceleration(V + (0.5)*k2v, alpha)

    k3x = dt  (V + (0.5)*k2v)

    k4v = dt * acceleration(V + k3v, alpha)

    k4x = dt * (V + k3v)

    

    V += (k1v + 2*k2v + 2*k3v + k4v) / 6

    x += (k1x + 2*k2x + 2*k3x + k4x) / 6

    

    return V, x


def takeoff():

    V = V0

    x = x0

    alpha = alpha0

    iterations = 0

    drag_values = []

    thrust_values = []

    while x >= 0:

        V, x = rk4_step(V, x, alpha)

        iterations += 1

        drag_values.append(drag(V, alpha))

        thrust_values.append(thrust(V))

        if alpha == alpha0:

            alpha = alpha_gr  

    return x, V, iterations, drag_values, thrust_values

SLO_distance, SLO_velocity, iterations, drag_values, thrust_values = takeoff()

time_to_liftoff = iterations * dt


print("Lift-off distance:", SLO_distance, "ft")

print("Lift-off velocity:", SLO_velocity, "ft/s")

print("Time to lift-off:", time_to_liftoff, "s")

print("RK4 iterations to lift-off:", iterations)


position = np.arange(0, SLO_distance, dt)

plt.plot(position, drag_values, label='Drag')

plt.plot(position, thrust_values, label='Thrust')

plt.xlabel('Position (ft)')

plt.ylabel('Force (lbs)')

plt.legend()

plt.title('Drag and Thrust vs. Position')

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post the details of the error message?

Answer (score 7):

```
return 0.5  rho  V**2  S  (lift_slope * alpha + max_lift_coef)
```

This is the problem.

In some mathematical notation you can write two terms next to each other, and it's understood that means multiplication, like `a b` implicitly means "a times b".

But Python does not work that way.  You need to explicitly put the multiplication symbol:

```
return 0.5 * rho * V**2 * S * (lift_slope * alpha + max_lift_coef)
```

Comment: `S  (lift_slope * alpha + max_lift_coef)`, in particular, is an attempt to call a *function* `S` with one argument, not `S` times an expression.

Answer (score 4):

You have many lines without clearly breaking up the operations with defined operators. This will break in Python. You need to specify the intended operation.

The mixed formats is tricky too. Might be getting issues from inconsistently referenced format types. I'd suggest improving the variable names too. (e.g., `acceleration_due_to_gravity` instead of `g`).

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple lines in this code that use variables without an operator between them, `return 0.5  rho  V**2  S  (lift_slope * alpha + max_lift_coef)` is just the first one. I assume you want to multiply, so you will have to explicitly add all the `*`s, e.g. `return 0.5 * rho * V**2 * S * (lift_slope * alpha + max_lift_coef)`.